# Variables not stored in the main() function in spyder?

Tags: python

I'm running the code below, which basically loads a `csv` file and applies some processing on the `df` dataframe. But I'm unable to access the 'updated' `df` in variable explorer once my code's execution is completed.. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv', index_col=0)
    df = preprocessing(df)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: could you provide **preprocessing()** function please?

Comment: Of course not, your function defines a *local* variable `df`. Unless `preprocess` creates some other lasting reference to that `pandas.DataFrame` object, when `main` terminates, that local variable no longer exists, the dataframe's reference count reaches 0, and that object is reclaimed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

df is first created inside `main`, which makes it a local variable. You need to return df for being able to access it.

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv', index_col=0)
    return preprocessing(df)

if __name__=='__main__':
    df=main()
```